# Implicit generic type in interface

Tags: c#, .net, generic-type-argument

I have one interface:

```
public interface ILabel <A, F> where A: IAddress where F: IFeatures
{
    A Sender { get; set; }

    A Receiver { get; set; }

    F Features { get; set; }
}
```

And one class inherited from this interface:

```
public class Label : ILabel<Address, Features>
{
    public int LabelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address Sender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address Receiver { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Features Features { get; set; }

    public string Identcode { get; set; }

    public string Base64 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to initialize Label object by ILabel without provide generic types at ILabel, like below:

```
ILabel label = new Label();
```

I know that this is possible in Java. Do you have idea how to achieve that ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generic type declaration requires defining type arguments, so you should use`ILabel<Address, Features> label = new Label();` or just `var label = new Label();`

Comment: This seems to be unecessary becuase when we initialize ILabel to Label then generic types are known. Maybe do you know any way to workaround that ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution:

ILabel:

```
public interface ILabel
{
    IAddress Sender { get; set; }

    IAddress Receiver { get; set; }

    IFeatures Features { get; set; }
}
```

Additional new class which use as abstract base class, like bridge

```
public abstract class BaseLabel<A, F> : ILabel where A: IAddress where F: IFeatures
{
    public virtual A Sender { get; set; }

    public virtual A Receiver { get; set; }

    public virtual F Features { get; set; }

    IAddress ILabel.Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return Sender;
        }
        set
        {
            Sender = (A)value;
        }
    }

    IAddress ILabel.Receiver
    {
        get
        {
            return Receiver;
        }
        set
        {
            Receiver = (A)value;
        }
    }

    IFeatures ILabel.Features
    {
        get
        {
            return Features;
        }
        set
        {
            Features = (F)value;
        }
    }
}
```

And Label class

```
public class Label : BaseLabel<Address, Features>
{
    public int LabelId { get; set; }

    public string Identcode { get; set; }

    public string Base64 { get; set; }
}
```